# ArrayList of ArrayList - initialization of ArrayList<String> and shuffling

Tags: java, data-structures, arraylist

I am writing a board game, and I defined my own linked Node class(to implement the order of positions).

There are 17 positions, and among them are three distinct special positions.

I want to implement this positions with ArrayList with "BLACK"s and "WHITE"s.

Since where the special positions are will be decided randomly for every game, I am considering using

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> _al = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(18);
```

so that I could shuffle the special positions

```
Collections.shuffle(_al);
HNode<ArrayList<String> _l1 = new HNode<ArrayList<String>>(_al.get(0), null, _l2);
HNode<ArrayList<String> _l2 = new HNode<ArrayList<String>>(_al.get(1), _l1, _l3);
```

and so on. (HNode's constructor's parameters are (data, prev, next))

My questions are,

Would the following line automatically create 18 ArrayLists of String objects?
Or should I (and could I) create them first and add them to _al?

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> _al = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(18);
```

Thank you.

Comment: It will create an `ArrayList` that will contain a backing array with 18 **empty** slots (it means, with `null` value) to insert `ArrayList<String>` inside it and a size of 0.

Comment: PLEASE don't use underscores with names, it hurts the eye :( (At least my eye)

Comment: and why don't you just use boolean?

Comment: @D180 sorry I don't get your point =\.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I mean instead of using "BLACK" and "WHITE" you can use false and true, which will reduce the RAM usage heavily.

Comment: @D180 ok, got it. I think that's a design issue, but even myself prefer to use an `int` or an `enum` instead of `boolean` since you can have `RED`, `GREEN` or `BLUE` or even more in the future.

Comment: @D180. It may be a nice idea(I never thought about it), but Java Collection classes only holds class types, so it has to be 'Boolean' wrapper class anyway. Another reason is that I need to add some other Strings than BLACK or WHITE in special positions.

Comment: This seems like the *perfect* situation for an `enum`.

Comment: @WChargin Yes, I think using an enum is the best solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for replies.
I decided to initialize everything separately, and add them and shuffle.